# Use variable to change flag to cut command in bash

Tags: bash

I have a file `test.geno.file.txt` which contains chromosome and alleles and some numbers in it (this one is SPACE separated, but I have another which is TAB separated):

```
marker allele1 allele2 id1 id1 id2 id2
chr11_96001606 C T 1.25893e-12 1 3.16228e-26 0.000999001
chr1_46021459 G T 0.969347 0.0306534 1.22034e-21 0.996035
```

I'm using a script that checks if it is tab or space delimited and stores the result inside the `FILESEP`variable:

```
file=~/Desktop/test.geno.file.txt
  
  if cat $file | awk '{exit !/\t/}'; then
  echo "Tab delimited" # tab file
  FILESEP=""
  else
    FILESEP="-d \ "
  echo "Space delimited with $FILESEP" # space file
  fi
  onlyfile=$(basename $file)
```

Basically, I want to modify the original file to get the chromosome names and positions separated. I'm using the cut command, but I would like to make it easier to change the delimiter flag (using the if statement and variable above)

Like this:

```
  POSFILE=${onlyfile%.txt}.pos.gz # Next command will generate it 
  cat $file | cut -d' '  -f 1 | perl -p -e 's/_([^_]+$)/\t$1/' | grep -v marker | gzip > ~/Desktop/$POSFILE # Keep position only chr \t pos
```

This is the output:

```
gunzip -c ~/Desktop/$POSFILE

chr11   96001606
chr1    46021459
```

But changing the `-d' '` with `$FILESEP`:

```
  cat $file | cut $FILESEP  -f 1 | perl -p -e 's/_([^_]+$)/\t$1/' | grep -v marker | gzip > ~/Desktop/$POSFILE # Keep position only chr \t pos
```

But this last command doesn't work...

Comment: Is the first word in the first line of the file always `marker`? In this case, you can set `FILESEP` simply to the character following this word.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming none of the fields contain spaces, I'd replace `cut` with `awk` where the default delimiter is *white space* (space, contiguous spaces, tab, contiguous tabs).  This would do away with the whole `if/then/else` construct do determine what to put in `FILESEP`.
In other words ...

Replace this:

```
if cat $file | awk '{exit !/\t/}'; then
    echo "Tab delimited" # tab file
    FILESEP=""
else
    FILESEP="-d \ "
    echo "Space delimited with $FILESEP" # space file
fi
....
cat $file | cut $FILESEP -f 1 | perl ...
```

With this:

```
awk '{print $1}' "${file}" | perl ...

# or if using zcat (per one of OP's comments)

zcat "${file}" | awk '{print $1}' | perl ...
```

**NOTE:** I don't work with `perl` but I'd be surprised if you couldn't emulate this `awk` script inside `perl` (ie, eliminate the `awk` call with some additional code in the `perl` script) ... ??

Comment: That is indeed way cleaner. Just tested it with tabs and spaces and it works fine!

Answer (score 3):

Quoting is crucial when expanding parameters. Not quoting a parameter when expanding is almost always an error and [shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) will rightfully complain about it.

The solution in this case is to always specify the delimiter:

```
if awk '{exit !/\t/}' "$file"; then
  FILESEP=' ' # a literal tab character. In terminal, enter by pressing Ctrl-v Tab, or Ctrl-v Ctrl-i
else
  FILESEP=' '
fi
cut -d "$FILESEP" -f1 yourfile
```

Comment: OK! Nice! I was using the `cat $file` in the awk command since my original file is compressed, so I'll look like `zcat $file | awk ...` in the end.

Comment: If you're using bash, `FILESEP=$'\t'` -- using [ANSI-C Quoting](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#ANSI_002dC-Quoting)